# send thumbnail image to another view for bigger image view

Tags: ios, image

i have 3 images in my display where i use CoreData to store them images and to view them in the display. Now i would like to touch these images and it goes large in another view. Ive tried using touch events bt nothing seems to work. Can anyone assist me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a transparent UIButton over the image and declare a IBAction on the button and get the image according to button tag. Then pass the image to next controller.

Comment: you can try it your self buddy I don't think you need a example for this. Just put a custom button over the imageViews from interface builder and assign an action to them. In the action get the image from array or whatever you have according to button tag then pass the image to next View controller.

Comment: hi there @Rahul Vyas. i was busy with some web development for this few days. I'm back with XCode... anyways i tried doing what u told. the custom button works, bt i assigned protocol delegate to a back button,  it doesnt work, and i also the image is not appearing. hurm, is there anyway for me to show u what i have done?

Comment: why you assigned protocol delegate to a back button?

Comment: i might have got the concept wrong, but i read it in a book that they use protocol to control delegation. how can i contact u as i only have 9 reputation points and i dont know much bout this site. but this place really helps ppl like me... haha

Comment: i also tried to use touch event on the image... but doesnt really work... i guess using a button is better...

Comment: You can mail me on this mail address rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com